# Is it a good idea to set day-long Session Time Out?

Tags: asp.net, session-timeout

Everytime my page is reloaded, I reset the session time out to 1 day.
Is this a good idea in the shared hosting environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's a very bad idea, and even rude, as every new session created will consume more and more resources and enough sessions will bring your and every other hosted app to its knees.

Are you just trying to avoid having to log in repeatedly?  Because you can use alternative methods of authentication with cookies once you pass the initial test.

Answer (score 1):

That is decidedly odd, you'd keep in RAM every single session object with all their object handles that you create throughout each day.

If you're just trying to prevent timeouts during use, why not just use an ajax call every 30sec-2min to a heart-beat page so the server refreshes the timeout for your application. This way, a 10min timeout will be more than sufficient.